# Rectangle.color behaves like an object rather than like a string

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I tried to make a function that will change button colors clockwise.
When I assign `property var acolor: buttons.itemAt(0).color`, the variable `acolor` changes value as `buttons.itemAt(0).color` changes. Why does this happen?

This is **main.qml** file:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Window {
    id: root
    visible: true
    width: 600
    height: 400
    title: qsTr("My Window")
    property int numberOfButtons: 9

    GridLayout{
        id: grid
        columns: 3
        anchors.fill: parent

        Repeater {
            id: buttons
            model: root.numberOfButtons;
            delegate: Mybutton {id: butt; color: Qt.rgba(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), 1); number: index}
        }
    }
}
```

This is **Mybutton.qml**:

```
Rectangle {
    id: rectangle
    width: 50; height: 100
    color: "red"
    property int number: 0

    MouseArea {
        id: mouse
        anchors.fill: parent
        property var acolor: buttons.itemAt(0).color
        onClicked: {
            function rotate()
            {
                acolor = buttons.itemAt(0).color
                console.log(acolor)//heare is #11754c
                buttons.itemAt(0).color = buttons.itemAt(3).color
                console.log(acolor)// but heare is #6c2c3d
                buttons.itemAt(3).color = buttons.itemAt(6).color
                buttons.itemAt(6).color = buttons.itemAt(7).color
                buttons.itemAt(7).color = buttons.itemAt(8).color
                buttons.itemAt(8).color = buttons.itemAt(5).color
                buttons.itemAt(5).color = buttons.itemAt(2).color
                buttons.itemAt(2).color = buttons.itemAt(1).color
                buttons.itemAt(1).color = acolor
            }
            rotate()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The title is horrendous, also the context of QML properties implies bindings which means it makes sense for the property change as another property that is bound to it changes. Finally, the issue here as noted in my answer is that QML treats color properties like objects rather than strings which was actually unknown to me. In light of this, I will change the title to a format that will be more useful for others who face that problem in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your design is wrong. It is conceptually backwards to put the rotation functionality in the button when it acts on the grid layout. The `rotate()` function should be a member of the grid layout, and the you simply invoke it `onClicked`.

Second, according to `typeof(buttons.itemAt(0).color)` the type of `color` is `object`. Which means that `acolor` is a reference to that particular object, which explains why that reference points to another value once you change the color of the item at index 0.

One way to trick it to implicitly convert the color to a string is to use it like this:

```
  var acolor = ""
  acolor += buttons.itemAt(0).color
  console.log(acolor)
  buttons.itemAt(0).color = buttons.itemAt(3).color
  console.log(acolor) // the same!!!
```

And now it will be preserved, because `acolor` is now a string rather than an object reference.

Also, you don't really need the `property var acolor: buttons.itemAt(0).color` part.

You can also explicitly convert the color to a string:

```
var acolor = buttons.itemAt(0).color.toString()
```

Also, by moving the rotate function to where it belongs you considerably simplify the mouse area in the button:

```
  MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: parent
    onClicked:  grid.rotate()
  }
```

Update:

Note that if we do it like this:

```
property color acolor

function rotate() {
  acolor = buttons.itemAt(0).color
  console.log(acolor)
  buttons.itemAt(0).color = buttons.itemAt(3).color
  console.log(acolor) // still the same
}
```

it would work as logically expected. Now `acolor` is of type `object`, but you have an object to object assignment, which transfers the value to the other object, whereas with `var` it behaves like an object reference.